# Best way to pass a 2d array into JavaScript from PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I have a PHP array I want to use in my JavaScript code. I'd rather not do something like `<?PHP $array['array2name'][0]?>` for all of the elements in it as it's number is unknown. I was going to do a while loop to write in some of the data into elements but I cannot seem to find an easy way to do this currently.

How do I pass a 2d array from PHP to JavaScript in the easiest way possible?

Comment: Lots of duplicates I can see in the right column. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421875/write-to-javascript-array-within-php-loop (addresses the same issue)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to transfer an array between PHP and Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393479/best-way-to-transfer-an-array-between-php-and-javascript)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a JSON Object using the json_encode function.  You can then read this with Javascript easily as it is a native javascript object. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
json_encode($array);
```

JSON is easily parsable in JQuery, but for pure JavaScript see here:

http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: Problem with this is you lost the order of your array during the parsing from string to JSON object on javascript side.
for example. array with key as 0 0.5 1 will be altered to 0 1 0.5 by javascript. This behavior varies by browser.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy method:

```
<script>
var arr = [];

<?php
    $phparray = array(array(1, 2, 3), array(4, 5, 6));

    foreach ($phparray as $i) {
        echo 'arr.push([' . implode(', ', $i) . ']);';
    }
?>

</script>
```

This isn't the "best" method, but hey it works.