# Using timeline Google Chart API in PHP - Date/Time formatting issues

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-api, google-visualization

I am trying to implement Google's Timeline API
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#controlling-the-colors

I am having issues with the date format as I am unsure of how to store/convert my time format to the correct format for the timeline chart.

My Database looks like this:
[image]

And I am trying to output a chart to look like this: (This is a hard coded example)

[image]

My current code looks like the following:

```
    <?php
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","smartcinema");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = "SELECT a.screen_name, m.title, s.show_startime, s.show_endtime FROM timetable AS t INNER JOIN showing AS s ON s.showing_id = t.showing_id JOIN auditorium AS a ON a.screen_id = t.screen_id JOIN movies AS m ON m.movie_id = t.movie_id";
$qresult = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
$rows = array();
$table = array();




$table['cols'] = array (
  array('id' => 'Screen', 'type' => 'string'),
  array('id' => 'Movie', 'type' => 'string'),
  array('id' => 'Start time', 'type' => 'date'),
  array('id' => 'End time', 'type' => 'date')
  );

while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qresult)){
  $result[] = $res;
}

foreach ($result as $r) {

  $temp = array();
  $temp[] = array('v' => $r['screen_name']);
  $temp[] = array('v' => $r['title']);
  $temp[] = array('v' => 'new Date(0,0,0,'.date('H',strtotime($r['show_startime'])).','.date('i',strtotime($r['show_startime'])).','.date('s',strtotime($r['show_startime'])).')');
  $temp[] = array('v' => 'new Date(0,0,0,'.date('H',strtotime($r['show_endtime'])).','.date('i',strtotime($r['show_endtime'])).','.date('s',strtotime($r['show_endtime'])).')');
  $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

}
$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
print_r($jsonTable);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);
    var container = document.getElementById('test');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);


    var options = {
      timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true },
      backgroundColor: '#ffd'
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }
</script>

<div id="test" ></div>
```

Comment: check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243501/use-of-group-concat

Comment: Can you in your answer type the final solution which works?

Comment: I tested again and it works, so thank you for the final solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was looking back over my code and instead of defining:

`var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);`

I was defining

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);
```

The variable name i was defining was incorrect so my working code is now :

```
<?php
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","smartcinema");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = "SELECT a.screen_name, m.title, s.show_startime, s.show_endtime FROM timetable AS t INNER JOIN showing AS s ON s.showing_id = t.showing_id JOIN auditorium AS a ON a.screen_id = t.screen_id JOIN movies AS m ON m.movie_id = t.movie_id";
$qresult = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
$rows = array();
$table = array();




$table['cols'] = array (
  array('id' => 'Screen', 'type' => 'string'),
  array('id' => 'Movie', 'type' => 'string'),
  array('id' => 'Start time', 'type' => 'date'),
  array('id' => 'End time', 'type' => 'date')
  );

while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qresult)){
  $result[] = $res;
}

foreach ($result as $r) {

  $temp = array();
  $temp[] = array('v' => $r['screen_name']);
  $temp[] = array('v' => $r['title']);
  $temp[] = array('v' => 'Date(0,0,0,'.date('H',strtotime($r['show_startime'])).','.date('i',strtotime($r['show_startime'])).','.date('s',strtotime($r['show_startime'])).')');
  $temp[] = array('v' => 'Date(0,0,0,'.date('H',strtotime($r['show_endtime'])).','.date('i',strtotime($r['show_endtime'])).','.date('s',strtotime($r['show_endtime'])).')');
  $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

}
$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['timeline']
});

function drawChart() {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);
  var container = document.getElementById('example');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  chart.draw(dataTable);
}
</script>
<div id="example" ></div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 3):

When you `print_r($jsonTable);` -- how does it differ from the following example?

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['timeline']
});

function drawChart() {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    cols: [
      {id: 'Screen', type: 'string'},
      {id: 'Movie', type: 'string'},
      {id: 'Start time', type: 'date'},
      {id: 'End time', type: 'date'}
    ],
    rows: [
      {c:[{v: 'Screen 1'}, {v: 'Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice'}, {v: new Date(0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0)}, {v: new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 0)}]},
      {c:[{v: 'Screen 1'}, {v: 'Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice'}, {v: new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 51, 0)}, {v: new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 22, 0)}]},
      {c:[{v: 'Screen 1'}, {v: 'Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice'}, {v: new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 42, 0)}, {v: new Date(0, 0, 0, 18, 13, 0)}]},
      {c:[{v: 'Screen 2'}, {v: 'High-Rise'}, {v: new Date(0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0)}, {v: new Date(0, 0, 0, 11, 52, 0)}]},
      {c:[{v: 'Screen 2'}, {v: 'High-Rise'}, {v: new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 2, 0)}, {v: new Date(0, 0, 0, 13, 54, 0)}]},
      {c:[{v: 'Screen 2'}, {v: 'High-Rise'}, {v: new Date(0, 0, 0, 14, 4, 0)}, {v: new Date(0, 0, 0, 15, 56, 0)}]},
    ]
  });

  var container = document.getElementById('example');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  chart.draw(dataTable);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: So when I print the json it looks like this:

{"cols":[{"id":"Screen","type":"string"},{"id":"Movie","type":"string"},{"id":"Start time","type":"date"},{"id":"End time","type":"date"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Screen 1"},{"v":"Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice"},{"v":"Date(0,0,0,10,00,00)"},

Comment: And I am not receiving any errors just a blank screen.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I went through your code and merged mine with yours and noticed where I was going wrong