# Use of group_concat

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following a table called LOPList:

[image: a busy cat]

I want results to be :

```
LOPID | EMP ID | TIME START (LOPStatus = 'Y') | TIME END (LOPStatus = 'N')

2     | 6      | 2016-03-24T20:05:27+00:00    | 2016-03-24T20:14:41+00:00

5     | 6      | 2016-03-24T20:07:59+00:00    | 2016-03-24T20:13:11+00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select LOPID,EmpId,
max(case when LOPStatus='Y' then TimeUpdated end) as time_start,
max(case when LOPStatus='N' then TimeUpdated end) as time_end  
from LOPList where JobID= 22 group by LOPID;
```

Comment: Seems to appear good when i enter in SQL. But not in php page.
& How can i add WHERE JobID= 22

Comment: @MohammedKumel: I have added the `where clause` in query. check once

Comment: Doesn't seem to work i tried that in SQL as well when i add WHERE. MYSQL ERROR: ` #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE JobID = '22'
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4 `

Comment: By mistake added `where clause` before `from` that's why you are getting error. check again

Comment: If you are limiting the records , you should put `Limit clause` just after the `group by LOPID`

Comment: If it is working with MySQL Workbench or any other client you are using , It will surely work from PHP page also. check the query again you are executing from PHP.

Comment: u mean like this :  from LOPList where JobID= 22 LIMIT group by LOPID;
I get this  : `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY LOPID' at line 5`

Comment: No put limit after `group by` like this :  `from LOPList where JobID= 22  group by LOPID LIMIT 100`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT list.LOPID,list.EmpID as "EMP ID",
listY.TimeUpdated as "TIME START (LOPStatus = 'Y')",listN.TimeUpdated  as "TIME END (LOPStatus = 'N')"
from (SELECT DISTINCT LOPID,EmpID  FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[LOPList]) AS list , 
(Select LOPID,LOPStatus,TimeUpdated from [TestDB].[dbo].[LOPList] where LOPStatus  = 'Y') listY,
(Select LOPID,LOPStatus,TimeUpdated from [TestDB].[dbo].[LOPList] where LOPStatus  = 'N')  listN
 WHERE listY.LOPID = list.LOPID and listN.LOPID = list.LOPID;

You should know some sql language besic knowledge,here you should use 'DISTINCT ' statement, thanks, hope can take you some help