# PHP & MySQL with Google Timeline Chart

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, google-visualization

I'm trying to create Google Timeline chart using PHP & MySQL but without any success so far. So after endless hours of trying I've manage this so far:

First, I tried to create json using PHP (I believe that I've missed something here)
PHP

```
            try {
                  $db = connectPDO();
                  $result = $db->query("SELECT naziv_plan AS name, 
                                        objava_odluke AS start_date, 
                                        datum_stupanja_glasnika AS end_date 
                                        FROM ispu_plan
                                        WHERE datum_donosenja_plana 
                                        BETWEEN '2014-01-01' 
                                        AND CURDATE() 
                                        ORDER BY datum_donosenja_plana ASC"); 

                        $rows = array();
                        $table = array();
                             $table['cols'] = array(
                               array('label' => 'Godina', 'type' => 'string'),
                               array('label' => 'Odluka', 'type' => 'number'),
                               array('label' => 'glasnik', 'type' => 'number')
                             );

                  foreach($result as $r) {
                   $temp = array();
                   $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['naziv_plan']); 
                   $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['objava_odluke']); 
                   $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['datum_stupanja_glasnika']);
                   $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
                    } 
                   $table['rows'] = $rows;
                   $jsonTable = json_encode($table,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
                   } catch(PDOException $e) {
                           echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
                   }
```

Using this block of code, I get this JSON (and it's valid, checked with JSONLint) But, I detected some unusual formatting and even after `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`

```
{"cols":[{"label":"Godina","type":"string"},{"label":"Odluka","type":"number"},{"label":"glasnik","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Stambenog susjedstva - Stubi\u010dki Trnac - I.ID"},{"v":2014},{"v":2014}]},{"c":[{"v":"Prostorni plan ure\u0111enja Grada Krapine - IV. ID"},{"v":2013},{"v":2015}]},{"c":[{"v":"Prostorni plan ure\u0111enja Grada Donja Stubica - I ID"},{"v":2014},{"v":2015}]},{"c":[{"v":"Generalni urbanisti\u010dki plan Grada Krapine - V.ID"},{"v":2015},{"v":2016}]}]}
```

And here is JS:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable;?>);
        chart.draw(data);
```

After running this whole block of code, I get this error

***Cannot read property 'v' of undefined***

Is there something wrong with PHP code?
1.Maybe there is problem with date formatting?

2. Why do I get some weirdly formatted JSON Example -- *Stambenog susjedstva - Stubi\u010dki Trnac - I.ID when I should be getting instead of  this ->***Stubi\u010dki***  this-> **Stubički**

When I run SQL i get something like this (example below:)

```
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| name|     |   start_date     |  end_Date       |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| example_1 | 2014-06-06       | 2014-12-27      | 
| example_1 | 2013-12-31       | 2015-06-07      |  
| example_1 | 2016-06-06       | 2015-12-31      |  
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
```

*
I want to get something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

## UPDATE 1

So, I've managed to fix some of the addressed issues:
First, problem with weirdly formatted JSON, fixed with *JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE*

So, instead of this code:

```
$jsonTable = json_encode($table,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

I used this :

```
$jsonTable = json_encode($table,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

On the timeline note I've  managed to successfully render timeline chart,but on x axis, instead of years and date it shows me hours.I believe that i've missed something when transforming from query to json.
(as seen in picture below)

[image]

I used this block of PHP code:

```
                      try {
                      $db = connectPDO();
                      $result = $db->query("SELECT naziv_plan, objava_odluke, datum_stupanja_glasnika 
                                          FROM  ispu_plan
                                            WHERE  datum_donosenja_plana 
                                            BETWEEN '2014-01-01' 
                                            AND CURDATE() 
                                            ORDER BY datum_donosenja_plana ASC"); 


                            $rows = array();
                            $table = array();
                                 $table['cols'] = array(
                                   array('label' => 'Naziv plana', 'type' => 'string'),
                                   array('label' => 'Odluka', 'type' => 'datetime'),
                                   array('label' => 'glasnik', 'type' => 'datetime')
                                 );

                      foreach($result as $r) {
                       $temp = array();
                       $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['naziv_plan']); 
                       $temp[] = array('v' => (int) strtotime($r['objava_odluke'])); 
                       $temp[] = array('v' => (int) strtotime($r['datum_stupanja_glasnika']));
                       $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
                        } 
                       $table['rows'] = $rows;
                       $jsonTable = json_encode($table,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                       } catch(PDOException $e) {
                               echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
                       }
```

And in JSON i get something like this `1402005600` for start date and in my table is formated like this `2014-06-06` and i believe that i need to get something like this `2014, 6, 6` to properly render and calculate timeline chart. 
Please help with my lifetime crisis :)

## UPDATE 2

Using whitehat knowledge and directions I'm feeling it that I'm one step closer to finally render this abomination :) Meanwhile, using directions and code that WhiteHat provided i created this:

```
                        $rows = array();
                        $table = array();
                        $table['cols'] = array(
                               array('label' => 'Godina', 'type' => 'string'),
                               array('label' => 'Odluka', 'type' => 'date'),
                               array('label' => 'glasnik', 'type' => 'date')
                             );
                        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        $date1 = new DateTime();
                        $date2 = "Date(".date_format($date1, 'Y').", ".((int) date_format($date1, 'm') - 1).", ".date_format($date1, 'd').")";

                        $temp = array();
                        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $row['naziv_plan']);
                        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $date2);
                        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $date2);
                        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
                      }

                   $table['rows'] = $rows;

                   $jsonTable = json_encode($table,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Output of json is this:

```
{"cols":[{"label":"Godina","type":"string"},{"label":"Odluka","type":"date"},{"label":"glasnik","type":"date"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Stambenog susjedstva - Stubi\u010dki Trnac - I.ID"},{"v":"Date(2016, 8, 30)"},{"v":"Date(2016, 8, 30)"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Prostorni plan ure\u0111enja Grada Krapine - IV. ID"},{"v":"Date(2016, 8, 30)"},{"v":"Date(2016, 8, 30)"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Prostorni plan ure\u0111enja Grada Donja Stubica - I ID"},{"v":"Date(2016, 8, 30)"},{"v":"Date(2016, 8, 30)"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Generalni urbanisti\u010dki plan Grada Krapine - V.ID"},{"v":"Date(2016, 8, 30)"},{"v":"Date(2016, 8, 30)"}]}]}
```

And i get timeline, but without lines :(

Something like this:

[image]

And this two errors:

**Expected number, "MNaN,0LNaN,40.992**

**Error:  attribute x: Expected length, "NaN"**

## UPDATE 3

Ok, I believe that I've manage somehow, and it works. Here is code below, hope it helps someone. Once again thank you WhiteHat :)

```
                 try {
                  $db = connectPDO();
                  $result = $db->query("SELECT naziv_plan, objava_odluke, datum_stupanja_glasnika
                                      FROM  ispu_plan
                                        WHERE  datum_donosenja_plana 
                                        BETWEEN '2014-01-01' 
                                        AND CURDATE() 
                                        ORDER BY datum_donosenja_plana ASC "); 

                  $rows = array();
                  $table = array();

                             $table['cols'] = array(
                               array('label' => 'Godina', 'type' => 'string'),
                               array('label' => 'Odluka', 'type' => 'date'),
                               array('label' => 'glasnik', 'type' => 'date')
                             );
                        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        // here I added rows in DateTime function, that was missing
                        $date1 = new DateTime($row['objava_odluke']);
                        $date2 = "Date(".date_format($date1, 'Y').", ".((int) date_format($date1, 'm') - 1).", ".date_format($date1, 'd').")";

                        $date3 = new DateTime($row['datum_stupanja_glasnika']);
                        $date4 = "Date(".date_format($date3, 'Y').", ".((int) date_format($date3, 'm') - 1).", ".date_format($date3, 'd').")";


                        $temp = array();
                        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $row['naziv_plan']);
                        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $date2);
                        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $date4);
                        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
                      }

                   $table['rows'] = $rows;

                   $jsonTable = json_encode($table,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
                   } catch(PDOException $e) {
                           echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
                   }
              ?>
```

Picture, to prove it:
[image]

Comment: And what a sample chart do you expect to have? might give us an example png and linked back to your question

Comment: @SIDU, to be fair I wrote google Timeline chart

Comment: OOPS, you should be able to help yourself then if you are the author! Well you might checkout topnew SVG chart at : http://topnew.net/chart - which is the best chart to use and simple!

Comment: @SIDU I believe that you misunderstood my answer. Nevertheless thank you for your help

Comment: [here is a recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39756555/5090771) showing how to format json, with dates, for google charts. it also links to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771), which is a full example for using ajax, to get json from php and draw a chart. should help...

Comment: @WhiteHat Thank you, I find this comment very useful :)

Comment: The solution which works is in the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233412/using-timeline-google-chart-api-in-php-date-time-formatting-issues/36238497#36238497