# Parse data from Laravel/PHP for Google Chart Timeline

Tags: php, laravel, google-visualization

Here is the sample code from Google Charts Timeline with static data. I am wondering how to add dataRows from a Laravel dataset.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('example5.3');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Room' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
      [ 'Magnolia Room',  'CSS Fundamentals',    new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
      [ 'Magnolia Room',  'Intro JavaScript',    new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
      [ 'Magnolia Room',  'Advanced JavaScript', new Date(0,0,0,16,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,19,0,0) ],
     ]);

    var options = {
      timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true },
      backgroundColor: '#ffd'
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }
</script>

<div id="example5.3" style="height: 150px;"></div>
```

Comment: recommend using json to load the data table, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756555/5090771)...

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a perfect solution from another thread. Modified the code to fit in Laravel

[Using timeline Google Chart API in PHP - Date/Time formatting issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233412/using-timeline-google-chart-api-in-php-date-time-formatting-issues/36238497#36238497)